# How to Add Active Class to Nav Link Through Pug or JS

Tags: javascript, pug

I can't get an active class for my nav links based on which url is currently active.

I had a mentor help me write this code and it was working:

```
if filename.replace('.pug', '.html').indexOf(pageLink) > 0
 a.active-nav-link= pageName
else
 a(href=pageLink)= pageName
```

but I came back to the project and there is a compiling error with the code now and when I change the block to just `a(href=pageLink)= pageName`, it compiles successfully, but the .active-nav-link class is obviously gone.

```
ul.reveal
 each pageLink, pageName in navLink
  li
   block pages
     a(href=pageLink)= pageName
```

How do I get the .active-nav-link class to be applied to the current page like it used to be. Maybe the code above is out of date and needs to be tweaked. I'm willing to try other simple approaches, as I'm not too advanced.

Comment: You mentioned a compiler error. Please tell us what it said.

Comment: @JackBashford "but I came back to the project and there is a compiling error..."

Comment: I should have added, I'm using Prepros to compile and the error I'm getting is "Cannot read 'replace' of undefined". So you have any idea if it might be my compiler or if their is a change we could make in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS expressions as attribute values in pug. Try this:

```
a(
    href=pageLink
    class=(filename.replace('.pug', '.html').indexOf(pageLink) > 0 ? 'active-nav-link' : '')
)= pageName
```

Comment: I tried the code, but my compiler is giving the error message above from my compiler.

Comment: I tested the code and had no issues, so it sounds like an issue with your compiler, not pug. Try searching for the error you’re getting in google or in the GitHub repo of the compiler you’re using.

Comment: Oke. I'll look through documentation, thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you guys, the code worked, I just switched compilers and it compiled without a problem. Thanks again, I've been trying to iron this problem out for several weeks!